# Symfony Access Control Causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Login Page

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I'm working on a Symfony application where I'm trying to deny access to the login page for authenticated users using the access_control configuration in security.yaml. However, I'm encountering an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in my browser.

Here's the relevant part of my security.yaml configuration:

```yaml
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: app_home
access_control:
        - { route: app_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why I was seeing the "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" problem in my Symfony project and wanted to share how I fixed it.

The issue was related from the deprecation of the **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** role.
I used **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** role to prevent logged-in users from going to the login page but that caused a loop and redirected users back and forth.

The tricky part was that now Symfony was sending not-logged-in users (who don't have any special roles yet) to the login page. That was causing the loop.

To solve this,I opted for an alternative approach using the **allow_if** option in the access control configuration.

Here's how I did it in my Symfony configuration:

```yaml
- { route: app_login|app_register, allow_if: "!is_granted('ROLE_USER')" }
```